# ToolTip MouseOver function on text in RichTextBox

Tags: c#

im working on code-editor (windows form) and i just want to know how to make tooltip in text something like this 1:

[image]

sample when i mousehover the text with "" tooltip will show then when i mouseleave tooltip will gone .or if i mouseover it to a different text, text in tooltip inside will change .

just like in actual code-editor.

with this sample code?

```
 toolTip1.AutoPopDelay = 5000;
        toolTip1.InitialDelay = 1000;
        toolTip1.ReshowDelay = 500;
        //toolTip1.ShowAlways = true;
        toolTip1.ToolTipTitle = "<)( Text ToolTip )(>";
        toolTip1.UseFading = true;
        toolTip1.UseAnimation = true;
```

anyone? pls really in need .thanks .

Comment: I don't understand what you're actually trying to do

Comment: @Shimmy mouseovering assigned text will trigger the tooltip to show then mouseleaving a text will trigger the tooltip to hide just like in actualcode c# code editor

Answer (score 4):

Set the tooltip to the control you want to show when it hovers on it:

```
MyToolTip.Show("Tooltip text goes here", MyButton)
```

or

```
this.toolTip1.SetToolTip(this.targetControl, "My Tool Tip");
```

You can also do it on demand, if you want to check some other info:

```
private void checkBox1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    toolTip1.Show("text", checkBox1);
}
```

Update

Use `GetCharIndexFromPosition` to check the text that the mouse is over, and show/hide the tooltip accordingly.

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/464085/WinForms-RichTextBox-ToolTip-like-Visual-Studios) is a good example.

Comment: sir i want to do it on text not on a tool . like an information box for every string i typed in richtextbox